# Does this property of covariance require independence between random variables?

Tags: probability, independence, covariance

Lemma 5.3.6 in this [page](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_1_covariance_correlation.php) states that:

$$\textrm{cov}(X+Y,Z)=\textrm{cov}(X,Z)+\textrm{cov}(Y,Z)$$

Does this property require that X, Y and Z must be pairwise independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$cov (X+Y,Z)=E((X+Y)Z)-(E(X+Y))(EZ)$$ $$=EXZ+EYZ-EXEZ-EYEZ=cov (X,Z)+cov (Y+Z).$$ So this identity is always true. Inependence is not required.

Comment: Thank you so much, gent!